# NodeJS, function call not returning undefined even after done

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, requestjs

Hello: i am new to nodejs and mocha. I am struggling with the return value from a function call. It is always returning 'undefined' even though (i think) i have used the callback done() appropriately.

In the following example, how can i ensure that the return value from get() always returns the correct value and not 'undefined'. In this function, I have used the requestJS module to open google.com and return the content-type. However, it currently returns undefined.

Thanks a lot!

**Updated made post feedbacks:**

- Included `Test Case 3` example, to implement `Callback`. **Result is:** I am now able to print the data as desired. However, i get and error telling me to call done(). Is what i am doing incorrect?

**Result post running on node terminal**

```
 suite
    PRINT DATA: 200 text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
    √ Test case 1 (607ms)

    undefined (<< ****** how to return the correct value?** )
    PRINT DATA: 200 text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
    √ Test case 2 (603ms)

    PRINT DATA: 200 text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
    √ Test case 3 
    Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
    ...
```

**Google.js**

```
var request = require('request');

describe('suite', function(){
    it('Tase case 1', function(done){
        var options = { url: 'http://www.google.com', headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}};     
        request.get(options, function (err, res, body){
            console.log("PRINT DATA: " + res.statusCode + ' ' + res.headers['content-type']);  
            //do some stuff here                        
            done();
        });        
    });

    it('Test case 2', function(done){
        console.log(get(done));
    });

    it('Test Case 3', function(){
        doCallback(callbackHandler);  
    });

});

function get(done){
    var options = {
        url: 'http://www.google.com',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/html'},
        encoding: null
    };     
    request.get(options, function(err, res, body){
        console.log("PRINT DATA: " + res.statusCode + ' ' + res.headers['content-type']);  
        //do some stuff here                    
        return done(), res.headers['content-type'];        
    }); 
}

function callbackHandler(data) {
    console.log("PRINT DATA: " + data.statusCode + ' ' + data.headers['content-type']);  
}

function doCallback(done){
    var options = {url: 'http://www.google.com', headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}, encoding: null};     
    request.get(options, function(err, res, body){           
        var finalData = res;        
        return done(finalData); 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that; you need to use callbacks or promises.

Comment: Thanks @SLaks for your directions. I have now added an example for `callbacks` to the original question. Kindly refer `Test Case 3`. I am now getting the data but i get a error telling to call done(). I dont know how to resolve this. Maybe my approach is incorrect. Please help.

Comment: You're passing two parameters to a function that only accepts one parameter.  What do you expect that to do?

Comment: @SLaks, i am totally stuck. i tried to remove the second parameter as well. The problem seem to arise inside `doCallback()` wherein there is a call to `request.get(...)`. What is the correct way to get this to execute? Thanks again.

Comment: Hello @SLaks, could it be related to node? I am using `Node v7.9.0` and `requestjs v2.81.0`. I tried it on [Run Kit](https://runkit.com/npm/request) (after removing the mocha elements) using `node v 6.9.0` and `request.get(...)` was called correctly.

Comment: Hello @SLaks, Thank You for directing me to the solution. Finally, found one way which i have added as `one possible solution` for future seekers like me. Kindly let me know if there is a better solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

**One possible solution (using callback)**

```
var request = require('request');

describe('suite', function(){
    it('Test Case 3', function(done){
        doCallback(callbackHandler, done);  
    });

    it('Test Case: 3A', function(done){
        doCallback(function(data){
        console.log("PRINT DATA: " + data.statusCode + ' ' + data.headers['content-type']);  
        done();        
    });  
});     

});

function callbackHandler(data, done) {
    console.log("PRINT DATA: " + data.statusCode + ' ' + data.headers['content-type']);  
    done();
}

function doCallback(callback, done){
    var options = {url: 'http://www.google.com', headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}, encoding: null};     
    request.get(options, function(err, res, body){           
        return callback(res, done); 
    }); 
}
```

**One possible solution (using promise)**

```
var request = require('request');

describe('suite', function () {
    this.timeout(10000);
    it('Test Case 3', function () {
        return doCallback()
            .then(function (res) {
                console.log(res.statusCode + " " + res.headers['content-type']);
            })
            .catch(function(res){
                console.log(res);
            });
    }); });

function doCallback() {
    return new Promise(
        function (resolve, reject) {
            var options = { url: 'http://www.google.com', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' }, encoding: null };
            request.get(options, function (err, res, body) {
                if (err)
                    reject(err); 
                else 
                    resolve(res);
            });
        }
    ); }
```

Comment: You should return the promise instead of using the `done` callback in `it()`.

Comment: Instead of passing a confusing extra parameter to the callback, you should make the callback an anonymous function inside the test and call `done()` directly.

Comment: hi @SLaks, done. Added new test case using anonymous function for `callback` example. And, for the `Promise`  example it works even if i `return then`. Please let me know what is the correct return statement & also why`return then` worked? Many thanks.

Comment: `return then` is meaningless; you're returning an undefined variable.  You should add `'use strict';` to prevent that.  You need to return the promise itself from the test method; see the documentation.  Your error callback is also wrong; you shouldn't have that at all.

Comment: hi @SLaks, would you mind elaborating a little on `You need to return the promise itself from the test method`? and also on `why i should not have the error callback at all`?

Comment: Your error callback doesn't actually do anything (you aren't calling `console.error`), and you have no reason to have one (you don't have any meaningful way to handle the error).  If you return a failed promise to the test runner, it will display the error.

Comment: hello @SLaks, been reading up on the links you provided. thanks for these.

Comment: @SLaks, Thank you Sir. Was able to update the promises solution only today. hope this is correct and hope it helps those in need in future.